# how to remove write protections of project and its files written in vc++/visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

how to remove write protections of project and its files written in vc++/visual studio 2008.Or how to change attributes of files present in vc++ project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will remove the write protection using Windows Explorer.

- Right click on the Project Folder
- Choose Properties
- Genreral Tab - Untick Readonly Flag
- Click on Apply then OK

If the code comes from Team Foundation Server or any other source control you will need to remove the source control bindings first before doing the above.

Comment: The Readonly checkbox was already unchecked for me at the top most solution folder.  But was "grey checked" for my subproject folders.  So I did the above for each of the subfolders on each project and it asked to apply them to all files and subfolders as well.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I simply went to the local file, right click on it and uncheck the read-only checkbox.
hope this is helpful.